# How to know which attributes are used on GROUP_BY in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, indexing, group-by

I am improving the database tables by adding indexes where appropriate.

I'd like to add indexes to attributes that are used on GROUP_BY queries.

Is there a way to automagically know which fields were used by GROUP_BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that there's a correlation between GROUP BY performance and the presence of indexes. If you have a query that runs slowly then I'd look to see indexes on the columns you have a predicate or a join on first of all.

Comment: To find slow queries, put this in your /config/environments/development.rb file

    `config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5`

Comment: The Bullet gem is also very handy -- it identifies situations where you should invoke eager loading, which is a big performance improvement for activerecord.

Comment: On the database side you can set 'log_min_duration_statement=n' where n is duration in milliseconds, or look into auto_explain http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auto-explain.html